# php mail() function not working in linux server

Tags: php, linux, email

I'm working on PHP mail() function. I have created a test file in my live site hosted in linux server. This is my test file looks like

test.php

```
<?php
ini_set('SMTP','smtp.mydomain.com');
ini_set('smtp_port',25);
$to      = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: abc@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: abc@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Successfully sent';
}
else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

But I didn't receive any mail. It always shows `failed`.
Is there anything missing?
I checked for a solution, but still its not working
**UPDATE :**

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'mail' ) )
{
    echo 'mail() is available';
}
else
{
    echo 'mail() has been disabled';
}
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$to      = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, "From:abc@mydomain.in")){
    echo 'Successfully sent';
}
else {
    print_r(error_get_last());
    echo '  failed';
}

?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
mail() is available failed
```

Comment: Try to send without any headers first like mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: existingemail@gmail.com");

Comment: make sure $to and $from email id's exist. In From, its better if you can include your domain email like info@example.com

Comment: no need to give ini_set('SMTP','smtp.mydomain.com');
ini_set('smtp_port',25);

Comment: first make sure your emails are working with mail function of PHP in your server. Otherwise you can also use phpmailer class for sending emails.

Comment: @AmitGupta tried everything, but still the same

Comment: ok add at top of your page: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: failed is coming or Successfully sent coming without any email?

Comment: Also have you seen your spam folder if email is coming there?

Comment: Also can you tell which server/hosting provider are you using?

Comment: SMTP of Google is  `smtp.gmail.com` https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229

Comment: @AmitGupta I have edited my code. Please check it.

Comment: now what output is coming? mail() is available failed?

Comment: @AmitGupta it shows `mail() is available failed`

Comment: In from, you are entering valid email?

Comment: @AmitGupta Yes. tested from mail server directly

Comment: Can you tell me your server name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161162/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-geeth).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this and restart apache2

sudo apt-get install sendmail
sudo sendmailconfig (answer Yes to everything)
sudo service apache2 restart